# C# having trouble in sending email with both **Plain-text** & **Html** content

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am having trouble in sending email with both **Plain-text** & **Html** content.
In **Outlook 2007** the **plain-text** message is never displayed.
And in Gmail email client by default **plain-text** is displaying. I need the **HTML** message to be displayed as default in both Outlook & Gmail, but user can change to plain-text if such settings are made on that system.

I am using following C# code to send emails:

```
    private void SendEmail(string server, string from, string userName, string password, int port , string recipients)
{

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from,recipients);
    message.Subject = "This email message has multiple views.";
    message.From = new MailAddress(from);
    message.To.Add(recipients);
    message.IsBodyHtml = false;
    message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><head></head><body><h1>This is some HTML text2</h1></body></html>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
    message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is some plain text2", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    client.Port = port;
    NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
    client.Send(message);
}
```

The problem with this code is that (I am not sure), that in **Outlook 2007** the email content is displayed initially like below image (default rendering HTML body as plain text):

[image]

When I right click & choose "Display as HTML", then the email content is displays like following image (rendering HTML body):

[image]

And when I use gmail.com to see the email then email content is displayed like following image (default rendering plain text):

[image]

**EDIT 1:** As suggested I have made changes to my code, now I can see the HTML Email content in **Gmail**. But in **Outlook 2007** after setting plain-text as default view I see the HTML tags as string and it does not show Plain Text which i have drafted which is slightly different from html. Also how do i test the plain text email in Gmail as now in gmail i am receiving only HTML View and i didnt find any way to see plain text view though i have clicked on view original and changed view=om to view=dom in the URL as i have read it on google somewhere.

```
private void SendEmail(string server, string from, string userName, string password, int port , string recipients)
{

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from,recipients);
    message.Subject = "This email message has multiple views.";
    message.From = new MailAddress(from);
    message.To.Add(recipients);
    message.Body = "This is some plain text2";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><head></head><body><h1>This is some HTML text2</h1></body></html>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
    //message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is some plain text2", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    client.Port = port;
    NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: from what i've read is to put HTML after the plain text.

Comment: Have you tried to set the body additionally?

Comment: Please see my edit "EDIT 1:"

Comment: Any updates people regarding my Edits.

Answer (score 2):

I would try adding the html view after the plain text view.

Also, I usually set the IsBodyHtml flag to true, even when I've got both views defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `MailMessage.Body` to the clear text. Then add the html text as you do via `AlternateViews`.
At least this is how I have always sent emails with both text and html.
The email client should automatically choose html if it's capable of showing that. It shouldn't display the 'Alternate view' as it does now.

**Edit**:

I would not set 'IsBodyHtml' to true, it might confuse the mail program, since it's plain text.

Also I would set Encoding to `Encoding.UTF8`, but I doubt that would solve this problem.

**Edit2**:

Just checked my mail sender code. I always set a 'message id' header, don't know if that matters:

```
 mailMessage.Headers.Add("message-id", "<" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + "@example.com>");
```

Comment: Your Edits didnt help in viewing Different Plain Text Message in Outlook. Also how do we check Plain Text in Gmail?

Comment: Sorry, Im' out of ideas :-)